# why not assign var a value into id field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.getJSON('getwarehousename',function(data){
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    $("#plantname").val(data[0][0]);
    var a = JSON.stringify(data[0][1]); 
    alert("PlantWH...."+a)
    $("#plantwhname").val(a);
    alert("wname.."+$("#plantwhname").val())
  }
});
```

In this variable a value is `plantwarehouse01`, but this value can not be assigned to `plantwhname` id field?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var html2="<label><select id='plantwhname' class='wname' name='store1'>";
  var ht2="<option selected='selected'>Select</option>";
  $("#plantware").html(html2);
  $.getJSON('findPlantwarehouseForMultiple',function(data){
    if(data!=0){
      for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        ht2+="<option>"+data[i].plantwarehousecode+"</option>";
      }
      ht2+="</select></label>";
      $("#plantwhname").html(ht2);
      $("#plantwhname").attr("Style","width:220px;");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: what element is the element with ID `plantwhname`. add the html mark up

Comment: Edit the question and add the code there.

Comment: add html mark up as well @KailasShimpi

Comment: $(document).ready(function()
{
 var html2="<label><select id='plantwhname' class='wname' name='store1'>";
  var ht2="<option selected='selected'>Select</option>";
  $("#plantware").html(html2);
   $.getJSON('findPlantwarehouseForMultiple',function(data)
    {
     if(data!=0)
    {
    for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
   {
     ht2+="<option>"+data[i].plantwarehousecode+"</option>";
    }
   ht2+="</select></label>";
   $("#plantwhname").html(ht2);
   $("#plantwhname").attr("Style","width:220px;");
   }
   });
});

Comment: The code you provide do not allow to reproduce the issue. Like the JSON url is not provided and the HTML is not complete. That is not "complete and verifiable". But I can say that you try to assign a value to a `select` element... Which sounds wrong. You should try to find the relevant `option` to set it as `selected`, instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your select option list and your new add option not same so new option not select so first add this option

```
$('#selectID').append($('<option>',
 {
    value: value_variable,
    text : text_variable
}));

$.getJSON('getwarehousename',function(data){
  for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
    $("#plantname").val(data[0][0]);
    var a = JSON.stringify(data[0][1]); 
    alert("PlantWH...."+a);
    $('#plantwhname').append($('<option>',
         {
            value: a,
            text : a 
        }));
    $("#plantwhname").val(a);
    alert("wname.."+$("#plantwhname").val())
  }
});
```

then select it using this code. hope this will help you